# GPU memory is large enough, but tensorflow deep learning model still run out of memory

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

> Our lab just installed one GPU server with ~12 GPU slots. For heat dissipation, we installed 6 TITAN RTX gpus every two slots.

TITAN RTX has 24G memory. 
This is large enough for our tensorflow deep leaning model training.
But still out of memory.
The main running log file is below:

Could you please give some help? Thank you all in advance!

```html
nohup: ignoring input
/home/xingyg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/xinglib/function.py:14: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
/export/disk3/xyg/xinglib/function.py:89: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  label = (label <= cutoff).astype(float)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:366: conv2d (from tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.conv2d instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:281: dropout (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.dropout instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:143: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:46: separable_conv2d (from tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.separable_conv2d instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py:209: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
2019-11-24 11:36:16.653546: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-24 11:36:18.338942: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x558b8aeb8a70 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339018: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339036: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (1): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339051: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (2): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339064: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (3): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339077: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (4): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339090: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (5): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.365581: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2100015000 Hz
2019-11-24 11:36:18.368617: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x558b8afb9d60 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.368698: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-11-24 11:36:18.369120: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 23.65GiB freeMemory: 23.48GiB
2019-11-24 11:36:18.369174: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385864: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2019-11-24 11:36:18.386000: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1266: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a 
future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350540: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 23.65GiB freeMemory: 23.48GiB
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 1 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350819: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N N 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350825: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 1:   N N 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350923: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-11-24 11:40:02.351154: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507478: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:267] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 120.88MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 657, Chunks in use: 654. 164.2KiB allocated for chunks. 163.5KiB in use in bin. 2.6KiB client-requested in use in bin
.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507921: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 1619, Chunks in use: 1616. 813.0KiB allocated for chunks. 811.0KiB in use in bin. 631.2KiB client-requested in use in
 bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507940: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 5. 7.2KiB allocated for chunks. 6.2KiB in use in bin. 5.7KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507973: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507989: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508015: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16384):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (32768):         Total Chunks: 55, Chunks in use: 55. 3.06MiB allocated for chunks. 3.06MiB in use in bin. 3.05MiB client-requested in use i
n bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508053: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (65536):         Total Chunks: 332, Chunks in use: 331. 40.61MiB allocated for chunks. 40.51MiB in use in bin. 40.48MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508072: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (131072):        Total Chunks: 103, Chunks in use: 103. 20.65MiB allocated for chunks. 20.65MiB in use in bin. 20.40MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (262144):        Total Chunks: 104, Chunks in use: 104. 28.53MiB allocated for chunks. 28.53MiB in use in bin. 27.79MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508111: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (524288):        Total Chunks: 175, Chunks in use: 174. 122.76MiB allocated for chunks. 122.02MiB in use in bin. 121.99MiB client-requested 
in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508130: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1048576):       Total Chunks: 29, Chunks in use: 29. 30.61MiB allocated for chunks. 30.61MiB in use in bin. 29.18MiB client-requested in us
e in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508147: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2097152):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4194304):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508179: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8388608):       Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 8.17MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508195: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16777216):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (33554432):      Total Chunks: 200, Chunks in use: 200. 7.93GiB allocated for chunks. 7.93GiB in use in bin. 7.88GiB client-requested in use
 in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (67108864):      Total Chunks: 103, Chunks in use: 100. 10.87GiB allocated for chunks. 10.63GiB in use in bin. 9.45GiB client-requested in u
se in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508248: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 15, Chunks in use: 15. 2.93GiB allocated for chunks. 2.93GiB in use in bin. 2.25GiB client-requested in use i
n bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508268: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 334.17MiB allocated for chunks. 334.17MiB in use in bin. 241.76MiB client-requested in u
se in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:613] Bin for 120.88MiB was 64.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508317: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.58MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 40.29MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 120.88MiB 
| Requested Size: 120.88MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508343: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.59MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 40.29MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 44.04MiB |
 Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.59MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 120.88MiB | Requested Size: 120.88MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 40.29MiB
 | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508392: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3cc000000 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3d38e0e00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3db1c1c00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508431: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3e2aa2a00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508443: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3ea383800 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f1c64600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508469: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f44af600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f6cfa600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508493: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f9545600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3fbd90600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508519: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3fe5db600 of size 211251200
nohup: ignoring input
/home/xingyg/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 ==
 np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/xinglib/function.py:14: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
/export/disk3/xyg/xinglib/function.py:89: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  label = (label <= cutoff).astype(float)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:366: conv2d (from tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.conv2d instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future versi
on.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:281: dropout (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.dropout instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:143: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a futur
e version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /export/disk3/xyg/autoML/Web/TFweb.py:46: separable_conv2d (from tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.separable_conv2d instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py:209: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
2019-11-24 11:36:16.653546: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-24 11:36:18.338942: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x558b8aeb8a70 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339018: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339036: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (1): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339051: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (2): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339064: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (3): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339077: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (4): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.339090: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (5): TITAN RTX, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-11-24 11:36:18.365581: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2100015000 Hz
2019-11-24 11:36:18.368617: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x558b8afb9d60 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.368698: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-11-24 11:36:18.369120: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 23.65GiB freeMemory: 23.48GiB
2019-11-24 11:36:18.369174: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2019-11-24 11:36:18.385864: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2019-11-24 11:36:18.386000: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/xingyg/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1266: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a 
future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350540: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: TITAN RTX major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.77
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 23.65GiB freeMemory: 23.48GiB
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350802: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 1 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350819: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N N 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350825: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 1:   N N 
2019-11-24 11:40:02.350923: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-11-24 11:40:02.351154: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 22844 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: TITAN RTX, pci
 bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507478: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:267] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 120.88MiB.  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 657, Chunks in use: 654. 164.2KiB allocated for chunks. 163.5KiB in use in bin. 2.6KiB client-requested in use in bin
.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507921: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 1619, Chunks in use: 1616. 813.0KiB allocated for chunks. 811.0KiB in use in bin. 631.2KiB client-requested in use in
 bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507940: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 5. 7.2KiB allocated for chunks. 6.2KiB in use in bin. 5.7KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507957: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507973: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.507989: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508015: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16384):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (32768):         Total Chunks: 55, Chunks in use: 55. 3.06MiB allocated for chunks. 3.06MiB in use in bin. 3.05MiB client-requested in use i
n bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508053: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (65536):         Total Chunks: 332, Chunks in use: 331. 40.61MiB allocated for chunks. 40.51MiB in use in bin. 40.48MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508072: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (131072):        Total Chunks: 103, Chunks in use: 103. 20.65MiB allocated for chunks. 20.65MiB in use in bin. 20.40MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (262144):        Total Chunks: 104, Chunks in use: 104. 28.53MiB allocated for chunks. 28.53MiB in use in bin. 27.79MiB client-requested in 
use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508111: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (524288):        Total Chunks: 175, Chunks in use: 174. 122.76MiB allocated for chunks. 122.02MiB in use in bin. 121.99MiB client-requested 
in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508130: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (1048576):       Total Chunks: 29, Chunks in use: 29. 30.61MiB allocated for chunks. 30.61MiB in use in bin. 29.18MiB client-requested in us
e in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508147: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (2097152):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (4194304):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508179: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (8388608):       Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 8.17MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508195: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (16777216):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (33554432):      Total Chunks: 200, Chunks in use: 200. 7.93GiB allocated for chunks. 7.93GiB in use in bin. 7.88GiB client-requested in use
 in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (67108864):      Total Chunks: 103, Chunks in use: 100. 10.87GiB allocated for chunks. 10.63GiB in use in bin. 9.45GiB client-requested in u
se in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508248: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 15, Chunks in use: 15. 2.93GiB allocated for chunks. 2.93GiB in use in bin. 2.25GiB client-requested in use i
n bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508268: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:597] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 334.17MiB allocated for chunks. 334.17MiB in use in bin. 241.76MiB client-requested in u
se in bin.
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:613] Bin for 120.88MiB was 64.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508317: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.58MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 40.29MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 120.88MiB 
| Requested Size: 120.88MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508343: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.59MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 40.29MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 44.04MiB |
 Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508373: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:619]   Size: 80.59MiB | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 0, prev:   Size: 120.88MiB | Requested Size: 120.88MiB | in_use: 1, next:   Size: 40.29MiB
 | Requested Size: 40.29MiB | in_use: 1
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508392: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3cc000000 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3d38e0e00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3db1c1c00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508431: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3e2aa2a00 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508443: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3ea383800 of size 126750208
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f1c64600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508469: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f44af600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f6cfa600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508493: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3f9545600 of size 42250240
2019-11-24 11:42:00.508506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:632] Chunk at 0x7fd3fbd90600 of size 42250240
```

Comment: Well apparently it's not enough. You would need to provide more info (code!!) such as how big is the model, the data etc.

Comment: I had just solved the problem. The method is to use tensorflow 1.11.0 instead of Tensorflow 1.13.1.  I guess all < 1.12 versions  are OK also.  So tf-1.13's  mechanism allocating  GPU memory is not very efficient to some extent.